# Pass Styled component as className to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am using [react-paginate](https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate) library that accepts class names in props to style internal components:

```
<ReactPaginate
    ...
    breakClassName={'break-class-name'}
    containerClassName={'pagination-class-name'}
    activeClassName={'active-class-name'} />
```

I am also using `styled-components`, so I would like to avoid style react components using plain CSS or `createGlobalStyle`. Is there any way to pass styles from `styled-components` to `breakClassName` and `containerClassName` props of `ReactPaginate`?

I tried this, but it does not work, because `Button.toString()` returns class name without styles:

```
const Button = Styled.button`
    color: green;
`

export default () => (
    <ReactPaginate
      ...
      breakClassName={Button.toString()} />
)
```

Code bellow also does not work, because `Button` has class name `my-class-name`, but this class name is without styles:

```
const Button = Styled.button.attrs({ className: 'my-class-name' })`
    color: green;
`

export default () => (
    <ReactPaginate
      ...
      breakClassName='my-class-name' />
)
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Wrapping the component with a styled-component and added nesting rules to styled component seems to be the only way here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to make `<Button as={Component} />`?

---

UPDATE:

You can use wrapper with classes

```js
const ReactPaginateStyled = styled(ReactPaginate)`
  &.break-class-name {
    //your styles
  }
  &.pagination-class-name {
    //your styles
  }
  &.active-class-name {
    //your styles
  }
`;
```

Comment: A tried this, but unfortunately it does not solve problem. I updated my question for more details.

Comment: This solution doesn't work because ReactPaginate does have a className prop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a simple way to pass a className down like that. But if you're trying to style a component from a library, they *should* allow for this pattern to work:

```js
const Button = styled(SomeLibraryComponent)`
  color: green;
`;
```

Styled components will "wrap" around the base component and try to pass styles to it. Most library components should work with this but I can't speak for all of them.

Comment: I updated my question for more details. Unfortunately the library does not accept `className` in props and even if it does not solve problem, because I need style more  internal components of this library, not only container.

Comment: Yes you are right. Because ReactPaginate does not accept a className, you can't wrap styled() around it.